# How i can check if the (SPItemEventProperties properties) contain a specific ListItem or not

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, farm-solution

I am building an event receiver inside my sharepoint 2013, which get fired when items are updated and the `ListTemplateId="100"`.

as follow:-

```
 public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

            base.ItemUpdated(properties);

            if (
                ( properties.ListItem["ProjectStatus"] != null &&
                  properties.ListItem["ProjectStatus"] != string.Empty &&
                  properties.ListItem["ProjectStatus"].ToString().ToLower() == "approved" )

                )

            {
```

Now the problem is that inside the sites which have this event receiver enabled,there are multiple custom lists which the event receiver should not fire on.

For that i am checking if the list contain a column named "`ProjectStatus`" before modifying the fields inside the event receiver. but the problem I am facing is that let say a custom list item (which does not contain a field named `"ProjectStatus"`) got updated, then my event receiver will raise the following exception :-

```
Column 'ProjectStatus' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

now i thought when i add the following check inside my If statement :-

```
properties.ListItem["ProjectStatus"] != null
```

this will prevent the exception from being raised.. but seems this is not true. so my question is how i can check if the properties.ListItem contain a specific column or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `ContainsField(string fieldName)` method

```
properties.ListItem.Fields.ContainsField("displayname of the field")
```

There is also a `Contains` and `ContainsFieldWithStaticName` method.

MSDN documentation is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection_members.aspx